# How to get the columns of a nested list as a new separate nested list

Tags: python

I have this task where I have to extract the columns of a nested list and make a new nested list with them. For example, if I have this list:

```
  m1 = [[1, 2, 4],[3, 0, 6],[0, 5, 1]]
```

The output is going to be:

```
  new_list = [[1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 5], [4, 6, 1]]
```

Or if:

```
  m2 = [[1, 2, 4, 5],[3, 0, 6, 5],[0, 5, 1, 5]]
```

Then the output is going to be:

```
  new_list = [[1,3,0],[2,0,5],[4,6,1],[5,5,5]]
```

It takes the columns and makes new nested lists with them.

Here is the code I tried:

```
    def get_all_columns(matrix):
        new_list = [] 
        for lista in matrix:
            i = 0
            while i < len(lista):   
                lst2 = [item[i] for item in matrix]
                new_list.append(lst2) 
                i += 1 
         return new_list 
    print(get_all_columns(m5))
```

This gave me the output:

```
    new_list = [[1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 5], [4, 6, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 5], [4, 6, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 5], [4, 6, 1]]
```

This gives the right list, however, it loops it too many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over multiple lists at the same time.

```
new_list = [[i, j, k] for i, j, k in zip(*m1)]
```

A more robust solution would be:

```
new_list = [list(rows) for rows in zip(*m1)]
```

Comment: This does not work for variable dimensions, right?

Comment: Very elegant and pythonic! Nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehensions:

```
new_list=[[l[i] for l in m1] for i in range(len(m1[0]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having an extra loop. Do this

```
m2 = [[1, 2, 4, 5],[3, 0, 6, 5],[0, 5, 1, 5]]
def get_all_columns(matrix):
        new_list = [] 
        i = 0
        lista = m2[1]
        while i < len(lista):   
                lst2 = [item[i] for item in matrix]
                new_list.append(lst2) 
                i += 1 
        return new_list 
print(get_all_columns(m2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
def get_all_columns(matrix):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        new_list.append([])
    for l in matrix:
        for j in range(len(l)):
            new_list[j].append(l[j])
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

m1 = [[1, 2, 4],[3, 0, 6],[0, 5, 1]]
new_array = np.transpose(m1)
print(new_array)
```

Result:

```
[[1 3 0] 
 [2 0 5] 
 [4 6 1]]
```